# How to get the main thread in java?

Tags: java, thread-safety

So I have a long running process that I want to encapsulate as a Runnable and dispatch it in a thread. To be more specific, I have a POST web service that creates a file in the file system but the creation of the file can take a very long time.

In the resource method of my web service, I want to be able to dispatch a thread to do the file creation and return the status 200. I don't think I can just do Thread.join because this would mean that the current thread would have to wait for the file creation thread to finish. Instead, I want to join the file creation thread to the main thread. Question is, how do I get the main thread in java?

Comment: There's no "main thread" in a web service/server.

Comment: Just in case, if you meant how to get the "current" thread then you can use Thread.currentThread() static method http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread()

Comment: =P well what is that thread that is analogous to the main thread in a web server? how bout the server thread?

Comment: What do you want to do after the file is created? When a thread calls `anotherThread.join()` it means that the thread intends to perform some action once it knows for sure that `anotherThread` has completed execution. In your case, since you have already returned a response to the caller of your webservice, they won't be waiting for anything else from your service. If there is some cleanup or post-processing steps that need to be done after the file creation, you can run that in the thread creating the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure whether I get you right. Here is what I understood:

You want to preform a possibly long running operation (file creation)
you do not want you service method to block while that task is exectued
you want the task executed in a thread that exists outside the boundary/lifetime of the single request.

Am I right so far?

If sou really recommend you look into the newer concepts in java.util.concurrent. The concepts described there should give you enogh information tackkle this

Basic credo: Don't think in threads, think in tasks.

General Book recommendation: Java Concurrency in Practice by Brian Goetz

Comment: do you have a link where I can read up more on this? Yes you got it right? I just want my web service to return the status created while it spawns a thread to create the actual file.

Comment: Definitely agree with this answer. Additionally if you are interested in checking the status of the tasks you should specifically look at Executor and Future in the concurrent package.

Comment: Regarding reference material: if your time-constraints on project completion can stand amazon's delivery times, I can only recommend the book mentionend above: Great introducory material and many examples wiht DOs and DONTs.

Comment: In addition: DZone has nice cheatsheets of a few pages on certain topics. There is also one on Java Concurrency: http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/core-java-concurrency

Comment: I ended up using the Executor interface. It was very awesome

Answer (score 1):

You will need to process the request asynchronously. A separate thread will be created for doing the heavy work and the request receiving thread will be free to process other requests. Please checkout following articles.

- [Asynchronous processing in Servlet 3.0](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/97-new-features-in-servlets-30-3.html)
- [Asynchronous support in Servlet 3.0 spec](http://ravi-redblacktree.blogspot.com/2010/08/asynchronous-support-in-servlet-30-spec.html)
- [Asynchronous Support in Servlet 3.0](http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/asynchronous_support_in_servlet_3)

Answer (score 0):

When you spawn the file-creation thread, you need to pass it some kind of reference to the parent thread, so it can communicate back (i.e. you provide something to enable a callback).

This could be the actual Thread object (obtained using Thread.currentThread, as someone said in a comment) or some other object that you use to signal when the file-creation thread is done.